# Как добавить модуль в exe

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller, exe, numba

У меня есть скрипт который нормально работает, но в exe файле он выдаёт ошибку, что нужен scipy для скалярного произведения. Как мне его добавить? Для компиляции я использую pyinstaller.

Я использую numba для ускорения python. Если убрать @njit то всё работает, но с ними exe'шник не видит scipy даже с --hidden-import.

Answer (score 3):

Это известная проблема, `PyInstaller` не видит импорты второго уровня.

> Как мне его добавить?

Варианта два:

1. Вручную прописать названия модулей в файле спецификации (spec-файл)

   `hiddenimports=["scipy"]`
2. При билде использовать флаг `--hidden-import`:

   `pyinstaller --hidden-import scipy`

[Оригинал вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/no-module-named-when-using-pyinstaller)

Comment: из за нумбы это не помогает

Comment: @rastrey вполне может быть, что проблему и не получится решить с нумбой, потому что конвертация питоновской программы в .exe - это всегда притягивание за уши всех необходимых зависимостей, и pyinstaller - это не официальная библиотека питона, поэтому не факт, что она поддерживается всеми новыми актуальными обновлениями, так что сильно на него рассчитывать всё же не стоит, в вашем случае уместнее отказаться от его использования